# World of Tanks redownloading everytime I log in?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network, world-of-tanks

I recently logged back onto World of Tanks on the Xbox 360. I downloaded the recent update, as normal, and played for some time. When I logged back on the next day, it started removing the content from my local storage and redownloading the game all over again! Surely Wargaming can't release so many updates one after the other?

I have no idea how to combat this problem, and it is driving me mad!

Thanks again!